# How to print plain text in POSTMAN Console without quotation marks?

Tags: postman, web-api-testing

I tried below in POSTMAN
**console.log('Hello World');**
**console.log("Hello World");**

Showing output in console as below in both the cases
**"Hello World"**

How to remove those quotation marks and print plain text in POSTMAN console like
**Hello World**

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in way... but if you really want to follow these steps.

1. View > Developer > Show DevTools (Current Window)
2. Navigate to the Elements tab in the DevTools
3. ctrl + f for `wf__qt` (this will show you the element that holds the quotes
4. click on this element to see it's styles
5. in the styles pane, find the `wf__qt` class and uncheck the `content: '"'` style

Answer (score 0):

the syntax is :

```
console.log(val)
```

Different ways to represent string is to enclose the string with anyof :

```
double quotes :" , single quotes: ' and string literal:  `
```

if you want to have string with the quotes escape it out or enclose with a different one

```
  console.log("'Hello world'")
  console.log("\"Hello world\"")
  console.log('"Hello world'")
  console.log(`"'Hello world"'`)
```

Comment: still it prints "Hello world" with quotation mark ("")